# access res/req from process uncaughtException

Tags: node.js, express

app.js

```
_app.configure(function()
{
    /**
     * app setup
     */
    _app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    _app.use(express.methodOverride());
    _app.use(function(req, res, next){
        console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
        next();
    });
    _app.use(_app.router);
    _app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err, req, res) {
    console.log( res );
    _winston.error(err.message, err.code);
});
```

When the uncaught occurs, I can show messages in console, but I want too send a JSON response to browser. How can I do this? How can I access res/req from uncaughtException?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module: https://github.com/baryshev/connect-domain addresses this problem by the use of domains (http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). It s a simple connect middleware that you use like this (taken from their github page):

```
var
    connect = require('connect'),
    connectDomain = require('connect-domain');

var app = connect()
    .use(connectDomain())
    .use(function(req, res){
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            throw new Error('Simple error');
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                throw new Error('Asynchronous error from timeout');
            } else {
                res.end('Hello from Connect!');
            }
        }, 1000);
    })
    .use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.end(err.message);
    });

app.listen(3000);
```

I have been using this module with success, a tip is to observe where you will introduce connect-domain in your stack: https://github.com/baryshev/connect-domain/issues/12

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible, as far as I know, because an uncaught exception may happen not only in the express callback but anywhere in the code. What you probably need is to use the express error handler:

```
_app.error(function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.json({ ... });
});
```